# Multiple Spartacus site deployment in CCV2

Tags: spartacus-storefront, sap-commerce-cloud

I am working in the project where the **Requirements** is to build:

- 2x B2B site (no sites are identical in terms of functionality)
- 1x B2C site

I know that we can't combine Spartacus B2B and B2C in single code base which lead to this following  **Questions**:

- Does CCV2 support multiple Spartacus site deployment?
- Will CCV2 support multiple contexts with Spartacus sites deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I heard from my colleague that it's possible to support multiple JavaScript storefront in CCV2 now.

For details about configuration & setup, please refer to these urls below:

- https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE_CLOUD_PUBLIC_CLOUD/b2f400d4c0414461a4bb7e115dccd779/1c26045800fa4f85a9d49e5a614e5c22.html
- https://www.sap.com/cxworks/article/2589633836/supporting_multiple_sap_commerce_cloud_storefronts

Comment: Thank you @i042416, the above links are really helps!